# R: loop through objects in global environment and write table in multiple file names

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have been googling for hours but still could not figure this out. I am looping through some objects in R global environment and save it into different file names. But an error always pops up in the final stage:

```
 Error in as.vector(x, mode = "character") : 
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

The idea is to take all the lists in the environment that starts with proj2, and eventually save them to a txt file. I guess it is because the file name to save also contains x that is directing my object names? But how do I save my files to different names without doing this?

Here is my codes:

```
savelist <- function(x){
x_up <- subset(x, padj <= 0.05 & log2FoldChange >= 0 )
x_up$fac_lab <- rep("treated_up", nrow(x_up))
x_f_up <- as.data.frame(x_up)[,c(7,2,6)]
write.table(x_f_up, file= paste(x, "up", sep ="_"), sep="\t",quote=FALSE, row.names=TRUE, col.names = FALSE, append = FALSE)
}
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "proj2")), savelist)
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The error says that one of the objects you are trying to save to a text file is an S4 class and can't be converted into a data structure like a vector or data frame. It's hard to help without more info about what exactly that object is, but it's not surprising to me that an S4 object might not be easily transformed.

Comment: Look at `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "proj2")), is.data.frame)` and verify that each of those objects are actually data.frames. (If they are not, you'll likely need some other function than `write.table` since the object isn't tabular).

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
All the objects are converted to data.frames except the x in the last line 
`file= paste(x, "up", sep ="_")`  
In here the x is a S4 type object but what I am aiming for is to save the file that starts with the same name as each x. What is the solution here?